# JMeter's ResourceLastAccessedTime GET request failed

Tags: authentication, authorization, jmeter

I am trying to use `JMeter` to test our Web Application.  We originally used `LoadComplete` to test our Web Application, but because `LoadComplete` is not able to run on a non-GUI mode, we were not able to use the **max stat’s** from our test server (strain our 8 CPU’s and 8GB’s of RAM).  That is why I moving towards `JMeter` (https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui).

The test includes **logging in, choosing a specific app, do a simple task through this app and then end the recording**.  The HTTP Requests, which are failing are printing **Failed Access** on their **Response Data** on the **View Results Tree**.

I used the **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** to record each HTTP request.  My `JMeter` project is failing on a few different HTTP Requests, which includes **oauthtoken Get Request** that includes **jessionid="item"**, a **GET resourceLastAccessedTime Request**, and a couple **GET resourceLastAccessedTime Requests**.  I tried to follow blazementer's guidance for how to use `JMeter` for **Login Authentication**, because these requests seem to be involved with the authentication of each user after logging in and the problem I am getting on **Response data** for each of these requests on the **View Results Tree** it says **Access denied**.   (https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743663-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication-).

One of the steps is to "copy and paste" the Parameters from the Post request after you login to these requests.  I can add these parameters to these requests right below where it says **Send Parameters with the request**, but our POST request only has two parameters (the login name and the password).  **Is there somewhere else to look for these parameters?**

I tried a combination of a lot of different attempts, but I am still unsuccessful (meaning: **I moved the Regular Expression Extractor to a few different HTTP requests and I moved which HTTP requests to put those parameters and I have not been successful yet**).

Do you know of a URL that could be helpful for this?

Comment: To summarize my problem.  The GET Request RecourceLoastAccessTime get's a "access denied" when using JMeter, but it works fine without using JMeter by just doing the login manually"

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust Test Script Recorder! It doesn't follow any logic while recording your requests. It just records requests processed through proxy as they are. In case you use parameters that can't be defined as constants, the best way would be to rewrite the script manually.
Be patient and spend some hours (only once!) to learn how to construct any test scenarios (even complex) manually using Jmeter GUI. It will save you a lot of time for debugging.
It seems like (just a guess) that your test scenario doesn't contain Cookie Manager item. Based on what you wrote above, it seems like after logging to serer (by sending POST with login and password) it sets some cookies by Set-Cookie HTTP header. These cookies should be included in every next request as a prove that you successfully logged in before (the most common logic for simple web applications). So, if you get Access Denied, means you didn't include appropriate cookies in test request. Use Cookie Manager for that.
Feel free to ping me in case you need any assistance. 
Jmeter help manual is all you need to know about how each element works.
P.S.: Jmeter also can generate distributed load from multiple slave servers, in GUI and CLI modes both. So, in case you need to stress your server yout, Jmeter is the best choise.
And welcome to Jmeter users family! Good luck.

Comment: Just as a test, I created another JMeter project with Cookie Manager & Cache Manager, while using "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" to record the HTTP requests, but I got the same errors.  I could create the same project manually, but I do not see what different I would create. What kind of difference would the HTTP Requests need if I create them manually?  They would get the same URL and I assume the same Headers on the "HTTP Header Manager".

Comment: When you record a test using Script recorder, required cookies can be defined as constant (hardcoded) values, not as values assigned by server. Another issue - with cookies level. Header Manager can be assigned as a child item, means it has an influence only on parents. Same for some other items. I usually create tests in the following way: I do steps manually in browser and record them using local proxy, then analyze the traffic and reproduce it using Jmeter. It's a bit longer than just record it directly, but saves a lot of time for troubleshooting.

Comment: I can do that through Firefox, which I can use firebug to record each request.  I will create HTTP Header Manager to match each parameter on each Request for each HTTP request.  A couple questions:  When I put the parameter for Authorization and/or Cookie.  I put Authorization for the name and then I put the 'digit' (letters and numbers) directly associated with it.  Is it true that the Authorization 'digit' and the Cookie 'digit' changes for each request?  If that is true, how I can make this request work?  Should I use "Regular Expression Extractor"?

Comment: Authorization Manager should be used only in case when your webapp shows Authorization DialogBox. For regular authorization just send appropriate parameters with your request. The set of requests affected by HTTP Manager depends on item level in your testplan. If it's defined as child for HTTP Sampler, then cookies will be changged for every request. If on the same level, then cookies your webapp sets for first request will be common for all similar requests.

Comment: I tried to look into sending the appropriate parameters with my request. The way I finding out the appropriate parameters is login while using firebug and afterwars I look at the POST request. But the only paramenters I see is username and password. I watch this video for giudance for picking out the parameters and using them. youtube.com/watch?v=hGkrSFKcj10 because I successfully tested with loadcomplete and I am using "authorization" & "token". I see a new “token” the request immediately after I login.  to get this token,

Comment: I am using 'regular expression extractor'. name (name I will use) regular expression (what and when JMeter should look for) ex. "(.+?)" for this request.  In “Template” I put “$1$”, which is referring to group 1.  Later requests still do not work.  What do you think I am missing?

Comment: Force Jmeter through local proxy (Fiddler, for example) or just add View Results Tree item to your test to check requests your Jmeter sends. It can help you to tune your test up. Also, make sure that you send appropriate cookies.